# What is a safe juice or liquid fast?

Tags: metabolism, juice, intermittent-fasting

For Lent I am doing a juice/liquid fast from sun up, to sun down. I can eat one meal at sun set, and snack before bed.  The thing is I was told I could “brake” my metabolism so that after my fast I would never lose lbs. Is this true? I know, “ask your doctor”, but I can’t afford one.  I know lots of other people that have done this kind of thing, and they all say to take in the calories I need and I’ll be fine. So what a safe way to do this? Should I stop my normal exorcize and Zumba until after the fast? Or should I just go about my life?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**"never lose"** is an extremely wrong statement. The body is very flexible and adaptable. The fasting system you are following will reduce your metabolism because your body will be receiving less calories with very low frequency, so the body clock will regulates itself to hold on to the calories you eat and slows down the fat burn process. **However** this is only true during the period of fasting ,and as soon as you stop fasting and start eating again regular meal, your body will re-adapt to it and raise the metabolic speed.

On a side note, Christian-wise, lent fasting is a sacrifice you make with a specific intention. In my personal opinion, you do not need to go extreme fasting during the lent period, and unless you have a specific reason to eat "this" few, you can make a sacrifice to stop **one** thing you like during the 40 days. For example, let's say, if you love eating potato chips, you can stop that for 40 days. You do not have to stop "eating" in general, and even more, fasting in Christianity is not mandatory, it is a personal sacrifice you do by choice.

So, i'd suggest, just choose one or two things you like and do not eat of them during this period. This way, you stay healthy, can still work and do daily tasks, and do not harm yourself by extreme low calories and nutrients intake.